# Is this USN Rollback?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

I have 6 Windows 2008 R2 Domain Controllers, all GCs, across multiple locations (2+2+2).

On my main site I have a clone of one of our DCs done a few month ago, usually totally isolated from the network. This morning I made a mistake of accidentally linking this clone to my standard network.  (Never right click on edit settings without selecting the correct VM) I left this connected for 25 minutes until I noticed the issue.  I ran `dcdiag` on a different site without particular issue notified.

I would like help to see if I am in big trouble per the Microsoft Support article [How to detect and recover from a USN rollback](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875495/en-US). I don't fully understand it.

This is the output of `repadmin`:
This is the clone of DC1 that I powered on this morning..

```
C:\Users\admin>repadmin /showutdvec DC1 dc=mydomain,dc=local
Caching GUIDs.
..
mainsite\DC2                   @ USN  28895532 @ Time 2014-02-26 12:41:58
mainsite\DC1                      @ USN 202723681 @ Time 2014-02-26 12:42:29

C:\Users\admin>repadmin /showutdvec DC2 dc=mydomain,dc=local
Caching GUIDs.
..
mainsite\DC2                   @ USN  28895538 @ Time 2014-02-26 12:42:30
mainsite\DC1                      @ USN 202723672 @ Time 2014-02-26 12:42:11
```

As I can see, I have:

- DC2: usn value for DC1: 202723672
- DC1: usn value for DC1: 202723681

As 202723681 is greater than 202723672 is that all ok ?

To be sure the replication is OK, I did the following tests:

1. Test 1

   - Block all traffic from my computer except to DC1.
   - Change my password
   - Try to authenticate with this new password on another computer --> OK
2. Test 2

   - Block all traffic from my computer except to DC2
   - Change my password
   - Try to authenticate with this new password on another computer --> OK

Are these tests results relevant?

Comment: This is the opposite of a USN Rollback - it's a regular replication delta, exactly as you would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your verbiage could be a little more clear, but assuming you ran `repadmin /showutdvec` on and against the actual DC1 (not its clone), those results indicate that you *probably* have **not** suffered a USN rollback.

[From the article you linked](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875495/en-US) (emphasis added):

> One way to detect a USN rollback is to use the Windows Server version of Repadmin.exe to run the repadmin `/showutdvec command`. This version of Repadmin.exe displays the up-to-dateness vector USN for all domain controllers that replicate a common naming context. To detect a USN rollback, compare the output of the `repadmin /showutdvec` command on the domain controller with the output of the same command on the domain controller's replication partners. **If the direct replication partners have a higher USN number for the domain controller than the domain controller has for itself**, and the `repadmin /showreps` command does not report replication errors between direct replication partners, you have compelling evidence of a USN rollback.

DC1 has a higher USN number for itself than DC2 has for it, so this does not indicate a USN rollback situation.

To be safe, run the same test against all replication partners (DCs 3, 4, 5 and 6), but it looks like the clone of DC1 you brought online was either rejected as a replication partner, or the IP conflict situation prevented replication.

Comment: Sorry for my verbiage. My message may show it, but I'm not very good in English and that's why I had some doubt about my understanding of linked article! By the way, I don't know how, but I would like to thanks jscott who edited my message to correct a huge number of mistake.
Have a nice day